# NullInjectorError: No provider for Router! error angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HeaderComponent -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HeaderComponent -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:994)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1292)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1234)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1102)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10836)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12069)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12559)
```

Comment: What did youu do to get the error? See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi,

My requirement is to add class in the nav while scrolling , has imported router, routermodule, navigation end etc.. user host  host: {
    '(window:scroll)': 'updateHeader($event)'
  },

var self = this;
    self.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    });


has done code like these, (which worked properly in prev project)

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same error when I generated my module using:

```
ng g m nameofModule --routing
```

This imported the following in @NgModule of the created Module:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
```

It's supposed to be forRoot not forChild. Its supposed to be :

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add `RouterModule` into your `AppModule`.

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router' ;

NgModule({
   imports: [
      ...
      RouterModule.forRoot(your routes here)
      ...
   ]
})
export class AppModule
```

Comment: I was able to use: 
RouterModule.forRoot([]) since I had no routes yet and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error specifies that no provider has been specified for Router in your project. To solve this you will need to add RouterModule to the exports in your module.

```js
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     RouterModule
   ],
})
```